# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting Blowfish/ECB/PKCS5Padding

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I have upgraded to `jdk1.8.0_131` from `jdk1.8.0_121` (jre as well) by uninstalling older and installing newer jdk and encryption code stopped to work.

Source code : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#BlowKeyEx

Error in eclipse :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Blowfish KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at com.encrypt_app.BlowfishKey.main(BlowfishKey.java:12)
```

Working without any error if run without IDE.

Steps I taken:

1. Went to `Windows > Preferences > Installed JREs` and changed Directory to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`. Ensured Build Path setting of project.
2. Tried restart eclipse, clean, refresh project.
3. Updated JAVA_HOME to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

-- Run same code without IDE and it worked.

4. Started eclipse with `-clean` argument (edited eclipse.ini)

Comment: What is your $JAVA_HOME pointing at?

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: @azro the code may be faulty, but the JDK/JRE seem to be pointing at the wrong version

Comment: Code is not faulty. It was working before Java upgrade.

Comment: @Nilesh. Libraries can change during an upgrade in such a way that code written for one version does not work for another. Not saying that;'s necessarily what happened here, but that is why we need version numbers in the first place.

Comment: If it was working fine before java upgrade and after upgrading it is not working then it means eclipse is picking latest jdk

Comment: @MadPhysicist That was the first thought. But I dont believe such a big change in same jdk version.

Comment: Does Maven build your code outside the IDE?

Comment: @Nilesh. You are most likely right about that, but it is possible that the algorithm name changed slightly perhaps?

Comment: if everything ic set in the correct way you can try to put **-clean** on top of eclipse.ini and start eclipse

Comment: @flob Offcourse I did that

Comment: @Nilesh Did you also update the Java Build Path on a project level?

Comment: @Nilesh Ok, I was just looking we nobody missed the obvious part :-)

Comment: @Nilesh. Just for reference purposes, you should probably edit in a list of all the steps you have already taken into the question. It will prevent further comment chains of this sort.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your suggestion. I did it. It will be helpful for others who stuck.

Comment: Answer is rather than EDIT. Create new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete library from build path and add again with updated JRE.

Comment: Thanks Amol. I went to Installed JREs and removed JDK entry, which I edited from old(Step 1). Added again, going through wizard. It helped.